# Where does Finn's blaster go?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

When Maz gives Lukes lightsaber to Finn he still has his blaster across his back. The next time we see him is when he comes out of the rubble and he only has the saber which he uses to take down a stormtrooper.

**Where did his blaster go?**